# Custom action sequence number

Tags: list, custom, custom-actions, list-item, elements-xml

I do not understand how does the **sequence number** work in *custom action definition*.

How can I decide my custom position (which number should I use?)

```
<CustomAction Sequence="600">
```

Answer (score 1):

The sequence number is used for ordering priority.

```
<CustomAction Sequence="0">
```

appears higher in the list of items than does

```
<CustomAction Sequence="600">
```

Property meanings are explained at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh500259(v=office.14).aspx